# testing for element tag name

Tags: javascript

When a user enters a bookmark using form['f3'] (a url and a title) it is immediately entered in via the dom - visually the title and the favicon are seen by the user.  Each bookmark is a link and and image under div Bb1c.  The insert is done alphabetically.  Basically, I need to insert the new image and link after the previous one.

The loop portion was created before I had added in favicons so it loops through all the child elements, but it only needs to loop through the  tags.  How do I check to make sure that it is an element of type a before doing a compare?  My for loop needs an && added to it.

This is rough draft code so if there anything else - contstructive criticism

```
  var a=document.getElementById('Bb1c'),
  b=document.createElement('a'), 
  e=document.createElement('img');
  c=document.forms['f3'].elements,
  d=a.firstChild,
  b.innerHTML=c[1].value; 
  b.href=c[2].value;
  b.name="a1";
  b.className="b";
  e.src=b.hostname + '/favicon.ico'; 
  e.onerror=function()  
    { 
    e.src = 'http://www.archemarks.com/favicon.ico'; 
    }
  while(d=d.nextSibling) 
    {
    if(b.innerHTML<d.innerHTML) 
      {    
      break;  
      }
    }
    a.insertBefore(b,d);
    return 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName) (or *`nodeName`*) property.:

```
if(ele.id === "foo" && ele.tagName.toLowerCase() === "span") {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Be careful about case of the tag: "In HTML this is returned in all uppercase regardless of the case used in the document; in XML the case used in the document is preserved."  I'd recommend leaving the `toLowerCase()` call in there.  Ref: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/tagName

Comment: @jfriend IE doesn't possess a XML parser, so no web-servers send web-sites as XML anyway, ergo, `tagName` will always be uppercase...

Comment: @Sime Vidas - if it's HTML< that means the tagName will be uppercase (e.g. "SPAN") so if it's going to be matched against "span", the toLowerCase() call has to be there.  That's what my comment was about.

Comment: @jfriend I see. But why not just `ele.tagName === 'SPAN'`... or at least `ele.tagName.match(/^span$/i)`... `:)`

Comment: You could do `=== "SPAN"`.  Without some info that I can trust that all older browsers do it per the spec, it seems safer to use  `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` and know what you're comparing to.  No point in using a regex for this as they are about the slowest way to compare to anything.